# Not able to access external url

Tags: apache, httpd.conf

I configured httpd.conf with below entries
       NamedVirtualhost *:8081
 and respective  ...etc. 
But still not able to access from external url. 
Can you please help me.

thank you

Answer (score 0):

Is apache listen 8081 ?

```
#
# Listen: Allows you to bind Apache to specific IP addresses and/or
# ports, instead of the default. See also the <VirtualHost>
# directive.
#
# Change this to Listen on specific IP addresses as shown below to
# prevent Apache from glomming onto all bound IP addresses.
#
#Listen 12.34.56.78:80
Listen 80
Listen 8080
Listen 8081
Listen 1111
```

Comment: <VirtualHost *:8081>
   ServerName xyz.com
    ServerAlias xyz
    DocumentRoot "/xyz"
      <Directory "/xyz">
        RewriteEngine on
        RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -f [OR]
        RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -d
        RewriteRule ^ - [L]
        RewriteRule ^ index.html [L]
        Options Indexes FollowSymLinks
        AllowOverride All
#        Require all granted
        Order deny,allow
        Allow from all
    </Directory>
</VirtualHost>

Comment: NameVirtualHost *:80
NameVirtualHost *:8081

Comment: error This site can’t be reached
xyz.com’s server IP address could not be found

Comment: Have you registered DNS records? What happens when you try to access your server from outside using server's IP address - write xx.xx.xx.xx:8081 in the address bar? where xx.xx.xx.xx - server IP.